# Re-entry Belgium in case of Belgium Residence Permit being stolen in London

Tags: uk, passports, belgium, lost-documents

I hold a Vietnamese passport and  have resided in Belgium for the last few years. So I have a Belgium residence card type A.

I am currently visiting London and my backpack was stolen on the way to the Eurostar train, all my travelling documents (passport + Residence card) are gone.

I went to Vietnamese embassy to apply for the new passport, so that is fine.

But my question is what can I do to travel back to Belgium with my new passport, a copy of my residence card, a police report?

Do I need to apply for new visa at the Belgium embassy (I went to the Belgium embassy but the old lady was terrible, she kept saying it was my fault and I should have left my ID card in Belgium)

Comment: If you leave your ID in Belgium how would you have got back into Belgium, or even been allowed on the Eurostar?

Comment: You are right, BritishSam, I have to bring it with me, that is why I lost it. The lady was just terrible (and maybe ... a bit stupid)

Comment: The only thing you can do is seek assistance from a Belgium consulate or embassy

Comment: Hmm, I did, and what I got from them was the silly answer, as you just pointed out @BritishSam. I here want to ask for advice from people with similar stories.

Comment: I'd go back and ask to speak to someone else if I was you. You can call them on 020 7470 3700 if you want an answer before going.

Comment: Was the lady in the embassy Belgian or British? In any event, I suspect that the proper procedure is to apply for a visa. Exactly how to submit such an application is unclear, because the instructions I can find concern only new applications for a prospective immigrant, not an application for a returning resident with a lost residence permit. You might try asking the [Agentschap Integratie en Inburgering](http://www.agii.be/juridisch-advies-in-vlaanderen-en-brussel) or the [Association pour le droit des étrangers](http://www.adde.be/services/service-juridique/service-juridique) for advice.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: do not let this awful experience get to you. Just focus on solvin the problem. Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Go to the police and report your documents as stolen. Give as many details as possible; ideally you should remember your passport number. Even better if ou have scanned copies of the lost documents to show and attach to the police report.
2. You need to get a new passport or an emergency travel document from [your embassy](http://vietnamembassy.org.uk)/consulate.
3. [You will need to apply for a new residency card at the Belgian embassy/consulate](https://www.belgium.be/fr/famille/international/documents_de_voyage/perte_de_documents) in the country you currently find yourself in

Quoting from the linked Belgian website:

> En cas de perte ou de vol de la carte d’identité et/ou du passeport à l’étranger, une déclaration doit être faite auprès de la police.
>
> Muni de cette déclaration et de photos d’identité, il vous sera possible d’obtenir un document (provisoire) [auprès de l’ambassade ou du consulat belge](http://diplomatie.belgium.be/fr/Services/Ambassades_et_consulats/ambassades_et_consulats_belges_a_l_etranger/) ou, s’il n’y en a pas, auprès d’une représentation d’un autre pays de l’Union européenne.
>
> La procédure sera facilitée si vous disposez d’une copie des documents égarés ou volés, de leur numéros et/ou de documents permettant de vous identifier (permis de conduire…).

Experience from other travellers indicates that you may be allowed to fly back with just a new passport and the police report. When my colleague had his French residency permit stolen in Prague he was allowed to fly back to France with the police report and his passport. Generally speaking airlines tend to be forgiving in these situations. Now, you are flying between the UK and the Schengen area so you will encounter immigration checks upon landing in Belgium therefore your mileage may vary.

In the future, my advice is that you save a scanned copy of your documents somewhere easily accessible - cloud, email, etc.. Having copies makes filing the police statement, and convincing immigration officers that you had a visa/residency permit much easier.

Comment: He is not flying within Schengen. He is flying from the UK into Belgium, crossing the Schengen border and therefore is required to have documentation to allow him to enter.

Comment: @kiradotee yes you are right I misread.

Comment: Who knows its passport number ? ^^'

Comment: @stbr I do. If you don't know it, I would suggest saving a scanned copy somewhere easily accessible. It makes things easier in case of loss/theft.

Comment: @JoErNanO The problem comes with data protection, I would not like to save it in a drive such as Google Drive because I don't want any company to have this accessible. Anyway that's a good thing to know it by heart but I am not sure that would be really useful, in any case the flight company will not let you fly without a real passport and the ambassy would be able to help you even without your passport number.¨

Comment: @kiradotee fixed it.